# Mysql Auto increament configuration in cluster

Tags: mysql, database

I have multiple mysql servers deployed in three different data centers. Now my database has few tables with Auto increment id column. I want these columns in all three data center must have unique id across the data centers. Is it possible in Mysql or i need to generate these columns programmatically ?

For example in data center D1 has table T1 with id 1, then data centers D2 and D3 must not generate id 1 for table T1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What we used to do, and the key point for your situation in the [link](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/replication-howto.html) posted by hardik, is to set different values for `auto_increment_offset` on each server and have `auto_increment_increment` set to a value greater than or equal to the total number of servers.

```
[Master]
server-id   = 1
auto_increment_increment = 10
auto_increment_offset = 1

[Slave1]
server-id   = 2
auto_increment_increment = 10
auto_increment_offset = 2

[Slave2]
server-id   = 3
auto_increment_increment = 10
auto_increment_offset = 3
```

This approach works, but in order to future proof, you need to set `auto_increment_increment` to some reasonable value, so that you can add extra servers in the future.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the replication read [this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/replication-howto.html) you can set Master D1 and SLAVE other.